# Kafka - Can access Topics but not Broker externally

Tags: apache-kafka

I stood up a local kafka instance and have opened up the the port 9092 externally. Everything works great inside the network. I can access topics and can create a producer to add messages and a consumer to reads messages. Externally, I am able to ping the port remotely, everything seems to be working there. When I connect to the port externally through Python I am able to read the topics just fine, but when I try to create a Producer or a Consumer it times out? Below are my listener and advertised listener settings. No matter what I change the advertised listener to, I am unable to get anything other then the topics. I don't have any security on right now, just trying to get the basics working. Is there an inherent security restriction on the topics externally?

Current Settings:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

I tried the below setting, but when I do that I can no longer reach kafka internally or externally

Tried These Settings to no luck:
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://external.ip.address:9092

Comment: Here is the error I get:  %3|1705415473.189|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator: (internal)X.X.X.X:9092: Connect to ipv4#(external)X.X.X.X:9092 failed: Unknown error (after 21104ms in state CONNECT)